# base64 bytesstring to string to bytestring again in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, flask

I'm trying to pass images down the wire in json objects.
{ image: "b'stuff'"} or whatever format it needs to be.

I've tried a variety of things and I keep getting the issues:

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/base64.py", line 521, in _input_type_check
    raise TypeError(msg) from err
TypeError: expected bytes-like object, not str

This is easily replicated because the behavior follows this:

```
np.zeros((32,32,3), dtype=np.uint8)
encoded = base64.encodebytes(image)

encoded = str(encoded) #this happens when you send via json

decoded = base64.decodebytes(encoded)
d_image = np.fromstring(decoded, dtype=np.uint8)
d_image = np.reshape(d_image, (32, 32, 3))
```

Is there any details on how to decode the string properly or get it into a numpy array?  I can't seem to get it to work for the life of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base64 is a binary-to-binary encoding in Python. It takes raw bytes and gives raw bytes to be sent anywhere. This can easily be converted to and from text, as base64 will always be ascii.

To convert the bytes into a numpy array, you want to use [`numpy.frombuffer()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html).

```
encoded = base64.encodebytes(image_bytes).decode('US-ASCII')
# Send this in the JSON
```

```
encoded = json['image'].encode('US-ASCII')  # Convert back to bytes
image_bytes = base64.decodebytes(encoded)

d_image = numpy.frombuffer(image_bytes)
```